# Shifting a huge number - assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, shift

I have a huge number which is loaded on stack and I access it using a `eax` . It
can not be stored in a register. I'm using `eax`  only to point at it's address (the number is natural type, meaning the first 4 bytes contain the sign, the next 4 the length and the others the actual value).

I have to shift it `edx` times.
I was thinking about starting from LSB shifting bits one by one (max 8 times / byte) and then copy those bits into the following byte. In order to do that, I would have to shift the next byte in the first place and so on until MSB position + 1(worst case) or until all the shifts were made and there is no carry flag left. P.S. I was obviously talking in this particular situation about `shl` but almost the same applies for `shr`.

Is there any simpler solution?

Comment: What's the maximum value in `edx`? And when you shift left, are you going to increase the length as needed, or truncate the result to keep the length the same?

Comment: @user3386109 i should increase the length.

Comment: You could use `shld`

Comment: What processor are you targeting? Does the code need to run on the original 8088 or 8086? (That would be the case if you were running this code in some kind of emulator.) Or are you free to write code that requires a 386 or later processor?

Comment: @CodyGray if he has `edx`, then it's either safe to assume 386+, or the OP has much bigger problem... ;) :)

Comment: How to use SHLD or SHRD: http://x86asm.net/articles/working-with-big-numbers-using-x86-instructions/#Bitwise-Shifting.  And of course you can/should work in 32b chunks (or 64b if available), to get twice as much done with each instruction.  Found with a google search for `x86 extended precision shift`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classic 8bit era idea was to use RCL (rotate left with carry) interleaved by `DEC counter + JNZ` - you can pause for a second and finally appreciate, why x86 `DEC/INC` instructions affect only zero-flag, but not carry (mystery solved).

So the code would go along these lines:

```
    mov   edi,address_of_last_byte
    mov   edx,count_of_bytes
    mov   cl,1
    clc   ; clear CF
loop_1_bit_left:
    rcl   byte [edi],cl    ; CF -> LSB, MSB -> CF
    dec   edi    ; preserves CF! Goes from last byte to first one
    dec   edx    ; preserves CF! Decrement counter
    jnz   loop_1_bit_left  ; till whole buffer is shifted
    ; CF has last bit, will be thrown away unless you do something about it
```

Now this leaves a lot to be desired...

How to save the MSB of buffer? I would first calculate the required size of buffer after shift (new_length = arg_length + (shift+7)/8)). And copy the input into it, and then shift not the arg_length bytes, but new_length bytes, that resolves problem with truncation of MSB.

But there's another problem, performance. The `rcl` on modern x86 CPU is unfortunately slow, so doing for example shift by 315 bits in this way is very bad idea. But you don't have to. You can do shift by 312 bits first merely by copying the input number already by 39 bytes off (toward beginning) into the new_length buffer, then do the remaining 3 bit shifts one by one by the loop above.

Plus if you will pad the output buffer enough, you can use dword/qword `rcl` variants (32b/64b code) to process more bytes at the same time.
(actually from your description it's not clear who's responsible for allocating the output buffer, if your code will return it somehow on stack (?? I'm not sure in which ABI is this possible with dynamically grown buffer according to shift amount), or allocate it on heap, throw in few more bytes on top, so you can modify few bytes after last regular byte of value, and you can work with dword/qword instead, plus over 4/8B aligned (!) addresses).

---

EDIT: the `word`/`dword` referencing variants of `rcl`/`rcr` will work correctly only when the whole big number in array is following little-endian way of x86, and the loop is following correct ++/-- direction (the bits b0-7 are at offset +0 in the byte array, and bits for example b80-b87 are at +10 offset and shifting right will go from MSB(+10) b87 toward LSB(+0) b0). My initial `byte [edi]` example is expecting it to be in big-endian way, with MSB starting at offset +0, and LSB ending at +, so the bits can be viewed in human order b87 .. b0, the little endian has them visually "reversed" per byte group (b7 .. b0 b15 .. b8 ... ... ... b87 ...b80) ... at least I think so, now I'm starting to be so confused. Simply write the code in one way, create unit tests for simple corner cases and verify results + fix it to produce what you expect. :D

---

Just make sure you don't update `edi` by `sub edi,4` (`sub rdi,8`) in such case, as that would destroy CF content, so instead exploit `lea edi[edi-4]` way of simple calculation done by addressing mode. And adjust counter to have correct `/4 || /8` value.

For best performance it would be probably still worth to shift by 1-7 bits in one go: for 1 bit left you may keep the `rcl` version, for 2-7 bit shift some variant of masking/oring values shifted by target amount in single go, using for example 32b registers to handle 16b read/write of buffer and keeping the shifted-out bits in upper half. Or if you will go that far, maybe the 1 bit variant with `shl/and/or` can be profiled, whether it's not faster than the `rcl` one. As the `rcl` is not used by compilers, particular CPU may prefer instead several `shl/and/or` instructions over single `rcl`.

---

Fun fact: my very first Z80 Assembly code which I wrote completely alone was doing this, shifting one huge area of memory 1 bit left (and right). As that huge memory area was actually video ram of ZX Spectrum computer, it was effectively moving image left/right by 1 pixel (ZX used 1 bit per pixel).

And I didn't realize it's possible to use CF from one rotate to other, so I did this by masking the bit separately, copying it into other register, then restoring it from there into new byte, etc.

So I wrote it, run it (did reset the ZX because of bug), fixed the bug, run it, and watched how the image is moving ... like 10 times slower (somewhere around 3 frames per second) than I expected from "almighty fast Assembly code". Then a friend of mine did show me how to just rotate it, which made the code run somewhere toward 20 FPS (which still made me realize that even the "fast assembly" is not unlimited and I have to work out my code a lot to get anything decent looking on the screen on the ZX).

Comment: And I forgot about `shld` (Harold's comment) ... which would made the 2-7 bit variant shift code almost easy.

Comment: `rcl` was slow on pre-modern x86 CPUs, too. Its just the *relative* performance that is different, since every other instruction was slow, too. :-) Speaking of fun facts and war stories, the shift instructions were so slow on the 8088/8086 when you were shifting by an arbitrary bit count that it was often faster to use multiple shift-by-1 instructions in a row!

Comment: @CodyGray Yep, on Z80 there was no performance difference between any variant of rotation or shift. Then again, they did allow for 1 bit at time anyway. Except there was special 4 bit rotation instruction (`rld / rrd`), looking somewhat like `shld`, but it actually keeps the 4 bits going out ready for next shift, so it can be chained similar to 1 bit r-cf rotations. I still regret I didn't ever need that one (partially because I always forgot it existed, while I was still active on Z80)

Comment: @Ped7g very interesting details indeed! Thanks for sharing :) I solved the algorithm using rotations.

Comment: @Ped7g: SHRD/SHLD examples from this tutorial: http://x86asm.net/articles/working-with-big-numbers-using-x86-instructions/#Bitwise-Shifting

Comment: @PeterCordes funny how many mistakes one does with this stuff without rigorous testing.. the tutorial has `test [bignum+8], 0x0000001F` test instead of `test [bignum], 0x0000001F` for shift right overflow detection, and my code will break upon `word`/`dword` `rcl` size as I didn't respect little-endian of x86 for large number itself, so only `byte` variant will work correctly. :/ But the `shrd/shld` examples are excellent, made me feel "duh, that was so obvious, why I didn't see it right away".

Comment: Yeah, so easy to get stuff wrong.  That's why I googled instead of trying to reinvent a load+SHRD algo.  (Of course, it would be more efficient to use register destinations for SHRD/SHLD, instead of introducing a store/reload latency inside the chain.  And if you want real efficiency, might consider 128 or 256b vectors.  http://gmplib.org/ has optimized asm for biginteger shifting.  I actually just remembered: I worked on GMP's rshift code as one of my first attempts at optimizing something in asm: Long thread: https://gmplib.org/list-archives/gmp-devel/2008-March/000770.html

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather ROL or ROR the values, cut away the bits that rolled over and apply them on the next byte (after applying the very same process to it)